# rails_admin - using a partial for a field on the show page resulting in caching related display issues?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

I have an intermittent issue with displaying a partial for a field's value on the show pages. If I include a partial like the following:

```
show do
  field :job_assignment_histories do
    pretty_value do
      if bindings[:object].job_assignment_histories.present?
        bindings[:view].render(
          partial: "job_assignment_histories/table", 
          locals: {job_assignment_histories: bindings[:object].job_assignment_histories}
        )
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I will occasionally get a list of the model's object reference like:

JobAssignmentHistory#25, JobAssignmentHistory#26, JobAssignmentHistory#27

instead of getting the partial included.

Is this related to pjax? I can't set pjax to false on a show page, so how do I work around this other than turning off pjax altogether?

Btw, this never happens in development, only in staging/production.

Comment: Just referencing your issue on github: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/2031

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20651623/where-to-put-partials-for-rails-admin-views  related?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be an issue where if the partial is being rendered an an error occurs, all that is displayed is a reference to the object.  This seems like a perfectly reasonable way of handling it from the standpoint of RailsAdmin.  But you can't seem to return back to a state where the partial is being rendered unless the server is restarted.  I would guess this has to do with pjax caching the view, but even when removing pjax this is the behavior.